# Invoke a javascript function of a website from java code?

Tags: java, javascript

Is it possible to use java code to invoke a javascript function that is in the sourcecode of a website?

Imagine a website with following code:

```
<script>
 function sayHello(name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}
</script>
```

Could I call "sayHello" from a client connecting to that webpage?
(I know I could call javascript from java if I have the *.js file locally saved. But I don't want this as the JS might change on the website I want to invoke the function).

```
 ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 engine.eval(..); //is it possible to invoke the JS function on the website?
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to write a client on a website that uses lots of ajax calculation for authentication with the server. So I somehow have to invoke these ajax functions (that are implemented as sourcecode in the login website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to parse content of script tags first (manually by fetching HTML page and then using e.g. RegExp find content of all script elements) and then pass it to the eval() as a string. Not pretty thing is that the JS code in `<script>` could be using some other JS code (external, loaded before this element etc.) so you might need to check for these "dependencies" as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it only via `Ajax call` or some old-fashion way like `iframe` refresh

Comment: It should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to call existing JavaScript in website as well as add some logic yourself.

You don't have to use Java here at all, you can simply inject your JavaScript into that page by

1. [bookmarklets](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)
2. Browser extenstions I'd recommend [Kango](http://kangoextensions.com/)
3. Or simply pasting the code into the browser console